# AS2 Version of MovieClip.getChildByName()?

Tags: flash, actionscript, actionscript-2

I'm trying to be responsible with my "DOM" references in this little Flash 8/AS2 project.

What has become increasingly frustrating is obtaining references to other movie clips and objects.  For example, currently my code to access the submit button of a form looks something like this

```
var b:Button = _level0.instance4.submitBtn;
```

I was hoping there was an instance-retrieval method for AS2 similar to AS3's `MovieClip.getChildByName()` or even Javascript's `document.getElementById()`.  Because hard-coding the names of these anonymous instances (like `instance4` in the above) just feel really, really dirty.

But, I can't find anything of the sort at [this AS2 Reference](http://flash-reference.icod.de/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the MovieClip was placed on the stage in the Flash IDE, you can give it a proper instance name in the properties panel.

If it was dynamically added, you can also give it a name, and additionally store a reference:

```
var my_MC=createEmptyMovieClip("instanceName", depth);
```

In either case, you can then adress them with `_parentClip.instanceName` or `my_MC.`

Comment: But then for deeply nested instances, is my only option to do something like _parentClip.childInstance.anotherChild.anotherChild.aaaaahhh?

Comment: You can always store a reference in a variable that is more conveniently accessible. 
Or: the clips themselves could pass a reference to a central manager. e.g. _root.addMenuItem(this); This function could, for example, store references to all menuItems in an Array, regardless of their depth.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple ways you can do this. The easiest way is to use Array notation. Your previous example, which looks like this:

```
var b:Button = _root.instance4.submitBtn;
```

would look like this in Array notation:

```
var b:Button = _root["instance4"].submitBtn;
```

So if you wanted to loop through 100 buttons already created and set the alpha to 0:

```
for( var i:Number = 0; i < 101; i++)
{
     var button:Button = _root["instance"+i].submitBtn;
     button._alpha = 0;
}
```

You can also use eval("instance4") to do the same thing, but I'm a little foggy on the scoping issues involved.

Answer (score 0):

You could just write it yourself (code not tested but you get the idea):

```
MovieClip.prototype.getElementByName = function(name : String) : Object
{
    var s : String;
    var mc : Movieclip = null;

    for( s in this )
    {
        if( this[s] instanceof MovieClip )
        {
            if( s == name )
            {
                mc = this[ s ];
                break;
            }

            mc = this[s].getElementByName( name );
        }
    }

    return( mc );
}
```